# ZoomingPDFViewer example error

Tags: ios, pdf, ios5

I'm trying to develop an app that can show a PDF file. I try to complete this with ZoomingPDFViewer
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

code that is in the apple library. When I mix that code with my code some function doesn't work. And if I make it with the same code (don't mixed) the  app throw this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a833f0'

I'm in SDK 5.0 the requirements says that I should compile it in SDK 5.1 but the sample runs perfect, the problem is in my project but I don't know what is my error.

I'll appreciate if someone can help me  with this strange error.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Class setting in Storyboard.

- View Controller -> Custom Class: ZoomingPDFViewerViewController and
- Scroll VIew -> Custom Class: PDFScrollView

The second setting is the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sending `-setPDFPage:` to an uncast `self.view` object.  Try casting before calling like so:

```
[(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage];
```

Double check your connections in IB, if you are using it, or make sure you are initing a `PDFScrollView*` object in `-loadView` if not.