# iPad PDF file display using apple's ZoomingPDFViewer source code

Tags: ipad, pdf, pdf-generation

I've tried to use the [ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) source code from 'developer.apple.com' and display a PDF file. The difference in my code is that I'm making use of a Nib file to add some extra features. I'm simply making use of the PDFScrollView and TiledPDFView class files from the source code. when I try to call the method [(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage]; I get the following error:

> **Smart_Reader[408:f803] -[UIView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x6ea09b0 Smart_Reader[408:f803] *** **Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception** '**NSInvalidArgumentException**',
>   reason: '-[UIView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6ea09b0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1283022 0x183bcd6 0x1284cbd 0x11e9ed0 0x11e9cb2 0x2a49 0x489e29 0x489133 0x48a3bf 0x48ca21 0x48c97c 0x4853d7
>   0x1ea1a2 0x1ea532 0x1d0dc4 0x1c4634 0x2176ef5 0x1257195 0x11bbff2
>   0x11ba8da 0x11b9d84 0x11b9c9b 0x21757d8 0x217588a 0x1c2626 0x1e5d
>   0x1dc5) terminate called throwing an exception**

I'm very much new to objective-c and this is my first post on stackoverflow.com. I will greatly appreciate any help from this great community

PDFReader.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ReaderViewController : UIViewController //<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *TapLabel;
}



- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;


@end
```

PDFReader.m

```
#import "ReaderViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "TiledPDFView.h"
#import "PDFScrollView.h"
#import "singleton.h"

@interface ReaderViewController ()

@end

@implementation ReaderViewController
{

}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

    NSString *name = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"NEWGEN KNOWLEDGE WORKS"];
    NSString *version = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GENIUS READER",name,version];

    TapLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    TapLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    TapLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    TapLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0f];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; //singleTap.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}


-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    NSInteger Totalpages;

    NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"fw4" withExtension:@"pdf"];

    CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument;

    myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef) pdfURL);// 1

    if (myDocument == NULL) {// 2

        CFRelease ((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    }

    CFRelease ((__bridge CFURLRef) pdfURL);

    Totalpages =   CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument);

    if (Totalpages == 0) {// 5
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(myDocument);
        }

    CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocument, 1);


    //[c setPDFPage:PDFPage];


    //PDFScrollView *PDFview = [[PDFScrollView alloc] init];
    //[PDFview setPDFPage:PDFPage];
    //[self.view addSubview:[singleton glpData].testsingleton]; 
    [(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Its seems like you are just using the same code which apple has given in that example,

Ensure that you have connected the IBOutlets in the IB if you are using it

```
(or)
```

Ensure that you have initiated the PDFScrollView in viewDidLoad if you are not using IB

Refer this answer --> [ZoomingPDFViewer example error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302469/zoomingpdfviewer-example-error)